# How to use another field for authentication in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

In the manual I can read:

> By default, Laravel uses the email field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a `username` method on your `LoginController`

However in my case I would like to use the `unique_id` field which is provided by my company to authenticate my user. This field is not a username so I feel bad about using the `username()` method to get this. Is there another way to tell Laravel Authentication to use something else than `email` to authentify my users?

Comment: You mean for the `make:auth`?

Comment: Yes the default one

Comment: You still define the `username()` method, you just make it return `unique_id` instead of `username`. That method simply tells the auth what column to use if you don't plan on using the default.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the `username()` method's name is quite unfortunate, but that's the way to go.

Comment: But still if I manually call `username` I will get a confused result which is not the username but an id.

Comment: Well, `make:auth` serves as a compromise for easy auth implementation. You don't need to use it, I personally don't.

Comment: Define a `username()` method, and a `uniqueID()` method that internally calls `username()`? Then call `uniqueID()` instead of `username()`... I hate that I just suggested that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `validateLogin` and `credentials` methods in your Auth/LoginController

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'unique_id' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge($request->only('unique_id', 'password'));
}
```

Comment: You must override `username()` method too.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the fact that the method is called `username()` and go for it.

Answer (score -2):

You can overwrite `username()` method in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class` like this:

```
/**
* Get the login username to be used by the controller
* You Username will be User $unique_id
*/
public function username()
{
    return 'unique_id'
}
```